# I'm downloading a video from its url that is coming from the server. Im downloading it locally and storage it in file system. How to play in expo Av?

Tags: expo, expo-av

im downloading a video and storing it using async storage and filesystem, i want to play that video by accessing it from async storage and using the path or the downloaded video, i want to play in expo av, it has an option of uri: videourl.
I also tried require but even that doesn't work. What else can i do?

trying to pass file path of file stored to the video av module to play video in expo

```
 <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: Path of the video here
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        isLooping
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.